# Angular: Need to resolve a chain of several operations (Observable)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I want to have a bunch of data ready the very first thing after a user logs in my app (keeping it cached in a Service).

I thought implementing this data-loading logic before resolving the parent route the user will be redirected to if login is successful, as a `Resolver`.

To be more specific: before showing the user's home page I would like to have a list of data already loaded and, if the list is not empty, have the first element of that list set as the selected element by default. So, this means, two `Services`:

- `ItemsService`: this Service will know how to request the list of items and keep it cached after the first request is done
- `ItemSelectedService`: this Service will know which item has been set as selected at anytime

And the following `Resolver`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemsResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private itemSelectedService: ItemSelectedService,
    private itemsService: ItemsService
  ) { }

  resolve() {
    this.itemsService.getAll()
      .subscribe((items) => {
        if (items.length > 0) {
          this.itemSelectedService.setAsSelected(items[0]);
        }
      });
  }

}
```

As `#resolve()` needs to return an `Observable` (`return this.itemsService.getAll()` would have just been enough...) but I'm not returning any because I need to subscribe and call `itemSelectedService#setAsSelected()` once the item list has been fetched asynchronously... what would be the right way to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving it a tap

```
resolve() {
    return this.itemsService.getAll()
    .pipe(
         tap(
             filter(items=>items.length > 0)
             do(items=>this.itemSelectedService.setAsSelected(items[0]))
         )
    );
}
```

> do / tap
>   Transparently perform actions or side-effects, such as logging.
>   https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flatmap** to resolve the observable in chain

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemsResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private itemSelectedService: ItemSelectedService,
    private itemsService: ItemsService
  ) { }

  resolve() {
    return this.getAll()
      .pipe(
        flatmap(items => this.setSelectService(item[0]))
      )
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.itemsService.getAll();
  }

  setSelectService(item) {
    return this.itemSelectedService.setAsSelected(item);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the difference between what you are proposing here and what I achieved so far? Isn't the behavior the same? I'm afraid `#resolve()` won't return an `Observable` so it will resolve immediately, instead of waiting for the data fetching to be done before resolving... am I right?

Comment: Resolve is returning a observable and chained observables are resoved inside it.

Comment: all right, now you updated the answer, it is returning and not subscribing.